How can I prevent users from deleting Chatter posts?
I've found that users in my org(s) are able to delete Chatter posts even though I've reviewed the relevant settings. I've checked the following:

Chatter Settings - "Allow users to edit posts and comments" is disabled
Manage Chatter Messages and Direct Messages = Disabled
Moderate Chatter = Disabled

Despite these checks, users are still able to delete Chatter posts, even when they do not own them. I'm frustrated and would like to know if there is a way to simply lock Chatter posts from being deleted by users.
Can anyone help me to understand how to effectively prevent users from deleting Chatter posts in Salesforce? I'm open to any solutions or additional checks I should perform, even creating a flow to notify me when someone tries to delete a post. But I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you in advance!

does user profile include modify all data or modify all on posts' parent object? Or Profile has Can approve feed postsor Close Converation Thread permissions. See doc

Hi, just checked these as well, both permissions are also disabled, and it doesn't have Modify All selected.
